# Resize native window

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos, cross-platform

Does anyone know of a cross-platform way to resize a native window - by native i mean one that runs inside of Windows', Mac's or Linux's windowing toolkit?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There isn't one - C++ itself has no graphics capability.

Comment: Is the window owned by your own app, or by another app?

Comment: Hi Thomas

The window will be owned by another application

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. There's even no cross-platform way to create and show a "native window" by using only standard C++.

There are cross-platform ways by using toolkits/frameworks that provide a platform-independent abstraction of the windowing system, including windows creation, resizing, custom drawing, buttons, etc...:

- Nokia's Qt: uses native drawing API's for its widgets, meaning everything will look "right", without dealing with platform abnormalities. Has great documentation and a very large featureset.
- wxWidgets: same as Qt, although some argue documentation is lacking and code can get messy.
- GTK+: looks ugly on Windows, written in pure c (has C++ wrappers, but is still c).

If you really want to abstract platform stuff yourself, you'll have to either split the source code and reimplement everything the aforementioned projects already have, or use A LOT of #ifdef's like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    // windows specific code
#elif defined(somelinuxdefine?)
    //Linux code
#elif defined(somemacdefine?)
    // Mac code
#endif
```

which is at the very least very difficult, messy, and unmaintainable.

Comment: Hey rubenvb

Thanks for the response. I'm not looking to create native windows, but i'm just looking for a toolkit that'll allow me to resize a specific native window on command. For example, Adobe Captivate 5 will automatically resize the window you're capturing according to the preset you define - so there must be a way to do it. It doesn't necessarily need to be cross-platform; if i can get it to work on Windows & OSX then i'll be happy. Linux is not an immediate concern right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry, don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

For X11 - (for example Linux, but no only),

you might be interested with :

- sources of [xdotool by Jordan Sissel](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), cause "tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc."

I am not sure, but it seems there is xdotool MacOSX and FreeBSD port as well.